# How to write Office Script equivalent data validation dropdown list?

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I searched the official documentation, found this formula ExcelScript.ListDataValidation, but i have no clue how to use it. tried writing this way but no help. Anyone knows how to use this function?

```
let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
const myrange = selectedSheet.getRange("CM4:CM5")
const listvalidation: ExcelScript.ListDataValidation = 
  {
    inCellDropDown:true, 
    source:"yes"
  };
  myrange.setValue(listvalidation)
```

Appreciate if there is guru out there could guide me a proper way to write the office script data validation list formula.

Comment: Hey everyone,

I have figured it out, use function below

const cUpdated = selectedSheet.getRangeByIndexes(firstDataRow, lastCol + 1, lastRow, 1)
  cUpdated.getFormat().setHorizontalAlignment(ExcelScript.HorizontalAlignment.center);
const listvalidation: ExcelScript.DataValidationRule = 
  { list:
    {
      inCellDropDown: true,
      source: "Yes,No"
    }
  };
  cUpdated.getDataValidation().setRule(listvalidation)

Answer (score 0):

```
const sh = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
const rangeValidates = sh.getRange("A1");
const dv = rangeValidates.getDataValidation();
const listvalidation: ExcelScript.ListDataValidation = {
    inCellDropDown: true,
    source: "yes, no"
};
const listrule: ExcelScript.DataValidationRule = {
    list: listvalidation
};
dv.setRule(listrule);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should add explanation.